# Boot setup bios laptop

Tags: boot, laptop, keyboard, bios, acer-aspire

I'm having a big problem. I have an Acer Aspire E1-572 laptop and all of a sudden a few keys stopped working. F2, F4, F8, F9, F12, left shift and so on... Most of them are really important, specially if I need to format the laptop. The thing is: To enter on the setup bios I need to press F2 and it's not working, I tried to use an USB keyboard and it's reading only after the Windows is loaded.
What can I do? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want fix the keyboard issue or the format of the hdd.

To fix the hdd format issue;

1. Assuming boot is set to USB/DVD before the hdd (if not try F10-> go to boot options screen), then you could try booting from a live cd/usb ([Knoppix(a very small one)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knoppix) or use [Yumi](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-a-boot-able-Windows-Installer-USB-key-/) for a windows version) and Use this live OS to format your hdd
2. Remove the hdd and use it in another system to format

To fix the usb keyboard issue:

1. Try another usb keyboard
2. Try another usb input (I had problems with usb 3.0 not discovering devices at boot)
3. Repair the keyboard buy a replacement keyboard (relatively easy)